# Pause embedded ruby interpreter and resume later

Tags: c, ruby, multithreading

I am running an embedded ruby interpreter inside a simulator.
I have wrapped the c api to the simulator so I can call it from ruby.
Unfortunately there is no blocking call to tell the simulator to run, instead it relies
on callbacks.

For example I can't simply do this.

```
set_input_values
tell_simulator_to_run
get_results
set_new_input_values
tell_simulator_to_run
get_new_results
```

Instead it seems to expect something like this.

```
call function that
  sets input values
  registers a callback
  exits
later the callback fires 
callback function then
  gets results from simulator
  sets new inputs
  registers next callback
  exits
...
```

What I think should be possible is this:

```
start ruby interperter
set input values via wrapped c api
call c function from ruby that:
  saves interperter / thread state
  registers a callback that when triggered will restore the state and resume the interpreter / thread.
  stop_the interpreter / ruby thread so the simulator can take over
later the callback fires a c function that does the following:
  restores interpreter / thread state
  resumes interpreter 
  gets results
  sets new values
...
```

I have seen something like this done in python,  so I am assuming it can be done in ruby as well.

As a first experiment I tried calling rb_thread_stop() thinking it would stop the thread at least and allow the simulator to take over.  If that worked I would move on to the trying to figure out how to save, restore, and resume,  but rb_thread_stop() results in a traceback `ThreadError: stopping only thread`

I have been looking through ruby's thread.c library but I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Not an answer but the [`async`](https://github.com/socketry/async) library provides similar functionality but with a lot more control and flexibility to a ruby `Thread`.

Comment: Thanks,  I will take a look and give it a try, but since it's 100% ruby I have some doubts, since its the the interpreter itself that is basically blocking the simulator .

Comment: Maybe you need to clarify the question. I am not sure what "the simulator" is but method calls as well as system calls (still a method) are blocking so ruby will wait for it to finish prior to continuing. This means you should be able to call the simulator from ruby as desired. Maybe I am missing what you are going for here but then as I mentioned clarification may be required.

Comment: I actually found a ruby repo/extension https://github.com/sunaku/ruby-vpi that does a very similar thing to what I want to do.  It wrapped the vpi interface, I need the vhpi interface (Verilog vs VHDL).  The interfaces are nearly identical so I will study what is done in that repo and maybe even fork it.