# Ruby crashes when embedded in a child thread

Tags: c, ruby, multithreading

I had hoped this would have been an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76186104/pause-embedded-ruby-interpreter-and-resume-later), but sadly, its not.

I am trying to run a single copy of ruby inside a child thread and have it communicate with the main thread.

The way the application I am running works is it loads a shared object library (foo.so) and calls a specified start up routine,  in my case I called it startup().

The start up routine must finish so that the calling app can proceed.
At the end of the startup, I can, and do, register a callback. The callback will be invoked later and then again that callback must complete in order for the main app to continue again. So at the end of that second callback I register a third callback.
The process continues until I am done and I don't register any more callbacks.  Each time the app calls one of the callbacks,  it's my chance to get and set some properties,  which I want to do inside a script running in the ruby interpreter.

I was coordinating the main and child thread (ruby) by what I thought of as a message passing scheme.

The main thread has two global variables, one that only ruby can write, and one that only the main thread can write, each thread then looks for a change in the variable that only the other thread can write.  When it sees the change it then acknowledges
the change by changing the state of the variable only it can write.

Here are my shared variables.  The main thread only writes to wait_for_simulator, and ruby only writes to wait_for_ruby.

```
pthread_t thread_id;
int wait_for_simulator = 1;
int wait_for_ruby = 1;
```

Here is what my startup and callback functions looks like. They both do similar things.
They wait until they notice that ruby changed its wait_for state, then as an acknowledgment they change the state of their wait variable and then wait for the next change from ruby.  When that comes, they register the next callback and exit.

```
void startup() {
    int result;
    char * ruby_script_and_parms = getenv("VHPI_RUBY_SCRIPT_AND_PARMS");
    printf("parms = %s\n", ruby_script_and_parms);
    wait_for_simulator = 0;
    result = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, run_ruby_script, ruby_script_and_parms);
    while (local_get_wait_for_ruby() == 1);
    wait_for_simulator = 1;
    while (local_get_wait_for_ruby() == 0);
    callback_reg(NULL);
} 

void the_callback(const vhpiCbDataT *cbDatap)
{
    if (local_get_wait_for_ruby() == 2) {
        return;
    }
    wait_for_simulator = 0;
    while (local_get_wait_for_ruby() == 1);
    wait_for_simulator = 1;
    while (local_get_wait_for_ruby() == 0);
    callback_reg(NULL);
}
```

In ruby I have something similar,  which I call when I want the main thread to take over for a while.  It basically tells the current callback it's done with its work for now, waits for an acknowledgment.  I then waits for the next callback before it lets more ruby code run.

```
def clock()
  set_wait_for_ruby(0)
  while (get_wait_for_simulator == 0) ; end
  set_wait_for_ruby(1)
  while (get_wait_for_simulator == 1) ; end
end
```

This seemed to work well when I ran the application with a small set of data,  but when I started trying to run with a larger set of data it crashes ruby.

I striped the entire application down to just this and it still crashes with one set of data and works with another.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ruby.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_t thread_id;

void * run_ruby_script(void * arg)
{
    int argc = 0;
    char **argv;    
    ruby_sysinit(&argc, &argv);
    RUBY_INIT_STACK;
    ruby_init();
    char *options[] = {"", "hello.rb"};
    void *node = ruby_options(2, options);
    ruby_run_node(node);
    printf("ruby is done\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}

void startup() {
    int result;
    result = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, &run_ruby_script, NULL);
    printf("result = %d\n",result);
    sleep(30);
}
```

The ruby script is just `puts "hello world"`

The interesting thing here is that I stripped out my waiting and replaced it with a long sleep.  After 30 seconds of sleeping you would have thought ruby was gone.  I do see the message I print saying "ruby is done",  but yet it's ruby that crashes at the end.  I guess I am not 100% sure it's crashing for the same reason, but I suspect it is.

I have seen some discussions that make me think I should be using ruby threads,  but I don't see how I can do that given that both the startup and the callbacks need to complete before the parent app will proceed.

Any suggestions?

One minor update,  I think I confirmed that if I don't call `pthread_create` it does not crash,  but I will go back and confirm that.

Comment: One thing to check is if this works properly outside of threads. What, *specifically* crashes? Can you get a stack trace?

Comment: I made a minor update,  I need to go back and confirm but I am pretty sure it doe not crash if I don't create the thread.

Comment: The next step is to find out what crashes and where.

Comment: `char **argv;` being uninitialized looks suspicious.  [The C-standard `argv` passed to `main()` is **never** `NULL` and will always point to an array of `char *` pointers with the last element - or `argv[argc]` - set to `NULL`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p2): "`argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer."  `char *argv[ 1 ] = { 0 };` should be a quick fix, although Ruby might expect the address of an actual pointer that it can modify.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I made that update and it had no effect.

Comment: I spent some time searching if anyone else had this problem before, and found a couple of instances with no resolution provided. Therefore we can expect that embedding Ruby within a `pthread` is going to be flaky (for some unknown reason). The quick fix is to just move Ruby to a separate process and communicate with a socket or named pipe instead.

Comment: yup,  that's the way I started,  and said, "Hey if I run in a thread I should be able to use the c api directly instead of writing some json based api",  I am pretty sure that's what I would need to do if it were in its own process, right?